# Access data sources across domains setting Internet Explorer

Tags: microsoft-office

Access data sources across domains setting

windows 7 ie explorer setting has Access data sources across domains setting disabled. We run a officejs app using angular to get data from a web api. The object is to migrate our windows 7 to windows 10 with the same security settings. However when the app runs under windows 10, pre-flight which cors requires does not start (even in fiddler no data is returned from request).

I would like specifics on what this setting actually is doing between the two environments. on windows 7, it doesn't affect the application at all set or not set. But on windows 10, only works when this setting is enabled.

Please let me know if more clarification is needed. Thank you, turtle

Comment: We would need MUCH more info about what you are doing.

Comment: Your question is not clearly described. Can you provide some samples?